# How can I install Website Administration Tool (WSAT) to webServer

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-membership

I designed my website using VS2010 and added membershipAPIs to authenticate users. Now I want to install the management pages of membership to my webServer so I can change users and roles in the remote Server. I searched the net but didn't get useful way. I guess I don't need to design my own management pages, right ?

Comment: Are you referring to the Website Administration Tool?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use the Website Administration Tool (WSAT) on remote servers, but here are some links to projects that provide similar functionality for you:

- https://web.archive.org/web/20210306174425/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/052307-1.aspx
- [http://peterkellner.net/2006/01/09/ microsoft-aspnet-20-memberrole-management-with-iis/](http://peterkellner.net/2006/01/09/%20microsoft-aspnet-20-memberrole-management-with-iis/)
- http://mywsat.codeplex.com/

Reference: http://forums.asp.net/post/3017713.aspx

Comment: The Kellner link died, it seems to be replace by http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa478947.aspx